# Where do iphone applications store data?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

What I mean is games such as Draw Something which are two player games and need to transfer data back and forth. Where is this data stored? Is it in iCloud, an external web server or somewhere else?

Comment: External webserver... Draw Something

Comment: Draw something uses a couchbase cluster. There is an interesting [article](http://gamasutra.com/view/news/168799/Scale_Something_How_Draw_Something_rode_its_rocket_ship_of_growth.php) about how draw something scaled with their success

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot, and different apps use different solutions. You may use iCloud to share data between different devices, but not between different users. That is, if I have an app installed on both my iPhone and iPad, the app developer could use iCloud to share data between devices. But iCloud is not suitable to share data between you and me. Many will use their own service, or something like parse.com etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Game Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/gamecenter/) for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store some data locally on the phone, you can store them as plist or using something like sqlite

But normally those games and other web service store users data in their remote server, either their own machine, or amazon, or some other back-end service provider like heroku

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Parse](https://parse.com/).  They basically do your whole backend for you, and you just need to interface with it using their API.

Comment: Note that Parce as a service shut down in January 2017. The code that powered it has been open-sourced, however, so you can create your own instance of their servers.